# React Native image cropping tool that works with Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Is anyone aware of an image cropping tool for React Native that works within the Expo setup. The very popular [react-native-image-crop-picker](https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker) doesn't. Is there any alternatives? I can't seem to find any.

Comment: Have you try https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/imagemanipulator ???

Comment: The images I want to crop are not from the camera or camera roll, they're images I'm getting from a server so the Expo image manipulator that you link to won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can download the image with `Expo#FileSystem` and then crop the cached image with `Expo#ImageManipulator`
Here is a sample

```
/*
 * @param link {string} URI of the image on the server
 * @param name {string} Name of the image with extension
 */
_downloadAndCrop = (link, name, cropSize = { width: 200, height: 200 }) => {
    FileSystem.downloadAsync(
       link,
       name
   )
   .then(({ uri }) => {
       console.log('Finished downloading to ', uri);
       //Your new cropped image
       const cropImage = ImageManipulator.manipulate(uri, [
                             crop: { 
                                 originX: 0, 
                                 originY: 0, 
                                 width: cropSize.width, 
                                 height: cropSize.height 
                             }
                         }], {});
   })
   .catch(error => {
       console.error(error);
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use aspect 4:3, 16:9, 1:1 and so on

```
import { ImagePicker } from 'expo';
```

are you getting photo from gallery?

```
const photo = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
   allowsEditing: true,
   aspect: [4, 3],
});
```

Comment: I'm getting the images from a server so the Expo image manipulator won't work unfortunately.